# How to close the PopUp window in TelerikRadGrid on save?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid

I am using `TelerikRadGrid` in [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET).  When I press edit or add new, a new PopUp window appears, when I fill the data and save everything is OK, but the popup window stays.

So how can I save and close the window at the same time (I know how to save, but I don't know how to close the window after saving?)

Comment: Did you set CommandName for the save changes button?

Comment: yes man i set it: CommandName="Update"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you search the Telerik's forum? [Popup Edit form not closing](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/popup-edit-form-not-closing.aspx#997804)

Comment: great man it is so easy... i am searching it from two days thnx alot

Answer (score 1):

When your page reloads after saving the data you need to put a JavaScript `window.close()`

Answer (score 0):

Or programatically you can try:

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemInserted(object sender, GridInsertedEventArgs e)
{
      e.KeepInInsertMode = false;
}
```